# Is there a better way to override Marshmallow.fields.List?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, marshmallow

I have created a NonEmptyList Marshmallow.fields.List object for ensuring that input JSON lists have at least one element. This is what I've done.

```
class NonEmptyList (fields.List):
    def __init__ (self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['validate'] = Length(min=1)
        super(NonEmptyList, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

This has a problem in that it overwrites the validate argument passed to the object. So if someone tries to use my new NonEmptyList with their own validate argument, it will not work. I tried to push on to the private field _validators, which I found in the code, but I got a name error. Plus that's not a documented field so it's not a great idea to make use of it.

Using: Python 3.6.7 and marshmallow-3.0.0b19

Answer (score 1):

I think your initial attempt was pretty close to working correctly. You'll just need to account for the possibility of a validate keyword passed in - this kwarg accepts a callable validator *or* a collection of validators. In both cases, you'd need to make sure not to overwrite the passed object, but instead just appending the min length requirement to the other requirements (if any).

Something like this:

```
class NonEmptyList(fields.List): 
    def __init__ (self, *args, **kwargs): 
        validate = kwargs.pop("validate", []) 
        if callable(validate): 
            validate = [validate, Length(min=1)] 
        else: 
            validate = list(validate) + [Length(min=1)] 
        kwargs["validate"] = validate 
        super(NonEmptyList, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Demo:

```
>>> class LibrarySchema(Schema): 
...     books = NonEmptyList(Str) 
...
>>> LibrarySchema().load({"books": ["The Stinky Cheese Man and Other Fairly Stupid Tales"]})
{'books': ['The Stinky Cheese Man and Other Fairly Stupid Tales']}
>>> LibrarySchema().load({"books": []})
# ValidationError: {'books': ['Shorter than minimum length 1.']}
```